# Run Wix MSI installation in WinpE

Tags: wix, inf, winpe, dpinst

I created an MSI using Wix. The msi contains a driver INF and Windows DPinst.exe. Now I am trying to run the msi in Winpe to update the driver.

How can I create an msi that can run in Winpe environment using Wix?
I used Wix V3

Answer (score 1):

There is no Windows Installer in WinPE so MSI's don't work, you have to use portable apps.  For installing drivers the command drvload *inf path*